# should I use the device toolbar or increase and decrease the viewport width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive website and I'm wondering about whether should I use the device toolbar to see the updates or just increase or decresae the viewport width as you see below:

[image]

everything is going Ok, at least that's what I thought in the beginning when I decrease the width of the viewport to the same width as the previous width (the width that I used for the device toolbar which is `320px`) I found the text collapsed I don't know why but I think that's because I didn't specify a precised height,
is that true?

[image]

and when I pick a specified device for example an iPhone X there Is some collapsing happened, so I don't know if my solution Is Ok but I think I should add a media query with a precised width and height according to the dimentions of that device so it's gonna be a specified design to that specific device, but I think with that solution I will end up with tons of media queries so I don't think It's the optimal solution.

sorry if that seems stupid but I'm a beginner and I'm doing my best to develop my skills so thank you in advance for responding

here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header-box">
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="text">
  <h1 class="big-heading"><span class="name">M.Amine Elwere</span> Front-end <br /> Web developer</h1>
</div>
<div class="vector-1">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="../vector/cloud.png"    data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="4000" class="img-dialogue" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="../vector/Png for the web/header minou.png" data-aos="fade-up" class="img-header" alt="">
</div>

</div>
<!--trapezoid-->
<img src="../vector/murva 1.1.png" class="img-murv"  data-aos="zoom-out-up" alt="">
<img src="../vector/Png for the web/header minou2.png" class="img-back" data-aos-duration="1500"    data-aos="zoom-in" alt="">
<div class="trapezoid">
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="text-2">
  <span data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000" class="saluation">Hi I'am Murva 1.0</span> <span  data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000" class="welcome">Welcome</span>
</div>
</div>


<!--Murva 1.0-->
<img src="../vector/murva 1.1.png" class="img-m" alt="">

<p class="leading"><span  data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1500" class="sub-leading__1">I think you got some questions.</span> <span  data-aos="fade-left"  data-aos-duration="2000" class="sub-leading__2"> I knew that, Ok let me just walk you through this lovely website </span>
  <p class="leading"><span  data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1500" class="sub-leading__1">I think you got some questions.</span> <span  data-aos="fade-left"  data-aos-duration="2000" class="sub-leading__2"> I knew that, Ok let me just walk you through this lovely website </span>
<span class="sub-leading__3"  data-aos="fade-right"  data-aos-duration="1600"  >and I will answer all of them on the</span><span class="sub-leading__4"  data-aos="fade-right"  data-aos-duration="2000" >ROAD...</span>

</p>

<!--Murva 0.0-->

<img src="../vector/Mino-1 hiding.png" class="img-m1"  data-aos="fade-left" alt="">
<p class="leading-2">
<span class="sub-lea__1"  data-aos="fade-right"  data-aos-duration="1500">Hi</span>
<span class="sub-lea__2"  data-aos="fade-left"  data-aos-duration="2000">I’m Murva 0.0</span>
<span class="sub-lea__3"  data-aos="fade-left"  data-aos-duration="3000">sorry I saluate you in the header but i didn’t introduce my self</span><br />
<span class="sub-lea__4"  data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-duration="2000" >I’m the first version in the <span class="word-0">Murva</span> family and who
told you <span class="word-1">“welcome”</span> above,that was my little brother,
ahh sorry I interrupt your walk I just wanted to say Hi  So </span>
<span class="sub-lea__5"  data-aos="zoom-in-up"  data-aos-duration="2000">We’ ll catch up later.</span>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 10000px;
}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-100px);
  }

  ,
  80% {
    transform: translate(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }

  ,
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }

  ,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@media (max-width:319px) {
  .header-box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .main-nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffcc;
  }

  .text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffcc;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }

  .vector-1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 37vh;
  }

  .img-dialogue {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 57%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .dialogue {
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #33cccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 55px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
  }

  .saluation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50vh;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    left: 30vw;
  }

  .welcome {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 31vh;
    font-size: 15vw;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 3vw;
  }

  .img-murv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 20.31rem;
    right: -2.44rem;
  }

  .img-back {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 36vw;
    height: 64vh;
  }
} /* END OF MAX-WIDTH 319PX */



/* @media (max-width: 375px) {
  .img-dialogue {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 78%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .sub-lea-3{
    top: 88px;

  }
} */

@media (min-width:320px) {
  .header-box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .main-nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffcc;
  }

  .text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffcc;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }

  .vector-1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 37vh;
  }

  .img-dialogue {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 57%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .dialogue {
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #33cccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 55px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
  }

  .trapezoid {
    clip-path: polygon(0 32%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
    background-color: #33cccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }

  .circle {
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    right: 3px;
  }

  .img-murv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 7.31rem;
    right: 1.56rem;
  }

  .text-2 {
    color: #ffffcc;
  }

  .saluation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 28vh;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    left: 5vw;
  }

  .welcome {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 23vh;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 3vw;
  }

  .img-murv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 12.31rem;
    right: -0.44rem;
  }

  .img-back {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 35vw;
  }

  .img-m {
    width: 40vw;
    transform: rotateZ(41deg) translateX(-75px);
  }

  .leading {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #33cccc;
  }

  .sub-leading__1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -149px;
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 0.81rem;
  }

  .sub-leading__2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -22vh;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    left: 30vw;
  }

  .sub-leading__3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14vh;
    left: 18vw;
  }

  .sub-leading__4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10vh;
    left: 34vw;
    font-size: 48px;
  }

  .img-m1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 25%;
  }

.leading-2{
position: relative;
font-family: Roboto;
color: #33cccc;
}

.sub-lea__1{
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.sub-lea__2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
}



.sub-lea__3{

    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
    left: 130px;
    right: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.sub-lea__4 {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: -68px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.word-0{
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.word-1{
  font-size: 1.12rem;
}

.sub-lea__5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -119px;
    left: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
}

}

@media (min-width:320px) and (min-height:578px) {
  .welcome {
    bottom: 21vh;
    left: 3vw;
  }

  .img-back {
    width: 37vw;
  }

  .saluation {
    bottom: 28vh;
    left: 20vw;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .img-dialogue {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 78%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .img-back {
    width: 43vw;
  }
.sub-lea__3{
      margin-right: 35px;
    }

    .sub-lea__4{
      margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
bottom:-80px
    }
}/*end of 375px*/

@media (max-width: 375px) and (max-height:578px) {
  .img-back {
    width: 30vw;
  }
}

@media (max-width:375px) and (min-width:578px) {
  .saluation {
    bottom: 26vh;
    left: 20vw;
  }

  .welcome {
    bottom: 21vh;
    left: 3vw;
  }

  .img-back {
    width: 37vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width:425px) {
  .img-dialogue {
    width: 31%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 70%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
  }

  .img-back {
    width: 38vw;
  }

  .saluation {
    bottom: 26vh;
    left: 20vw;
  }

  .welcome {
    bottom: 20vh;
  }

  .sub-lea__3{
        margin-right: 53px;
  }
  .sub-lea__4 {
    margin-right: 34px;
}

.sub-leading__1 {
    margin-left: 25px;
}


}

@media (min-width:425px) and (max-height:578px) {
  .img-back {
    width: 30vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .main-nav__items {
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .img-dialogue {
    width: 20%;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .trapezoid {
    clip-path: polygon(0 32%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
    background-color: #33cccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 83vh;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }

  .circle {
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 171px;
    right: 3px;
  }

  .saluation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50vh;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    left: 30vw;
  }

  .welcome {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 31vh;
    font-size: 15vw;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 3vw;
  }

  .img-murv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 20.31rem;
    right: -2.44rem;
  }

  .img-back {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 25vw;
      height: 57vh;
  }

  .img-m {
      transform: rotateZ(41deg) translateX(-167px);
  }

  .sub-leading__1 {
      top: -330px;
      left: 218px;
      font-size: 23px;
  }

  .sub-leading__2 {
    top: -52vh;
    font-size: 21px;
    left: 21vw;
    font-weight: 100;
}

}

@media (min-width:768px) and (min-height:1024px) {
  .img-dialogue {
    width: 36%;
    left: 21%;
  }

  .main-nav {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 49%;
  }

  .saluation {
    bottom: 41vh;
    left: 30vw;
  }

  .img-murv {
    width: 25.31rem;
    right: -5.44rem;
  }

  .circle {
    top: 299px;
    right: 13px;
  }

  .img-back {
    width: 33vw;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and(min-height:578px) {
  .img-back {
    width: 32vw;
    height: 55vh;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you `<p>` elements containing the text in a `<div>` with the class container and give it a `display: flex;` property.  That should help.

**EDIT:** I would also recommend using a grid system with your design.  Something like [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), or [both](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout).  It will help with the positioning of the text you have on the site.  It will save a lot of the headaches you have currently.

As for media queries, I wouldn't worry about specifying a `max-height` within the query.  Just the width.  My approach to responsive design is to use the resolutions based on the device screen size (like you have stated with iPhone X), then fix anything in-between that is completely broken.  It also may benefit you to look into a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com), as it is designed to be responsive and may save you some headache that comes from vanilla html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use px and use 'ems' (e.g. 16px = 1em) as a measurement. You can read more about the problems with using px here https://css-tricks.com/why-ems/